# Node reference + i18n - How to display only referenced nodes for the current language?

Tags: i18n-l10n, nodes

I have two content types with multilingual content (French/English), Publications and Profils.

I have set up a node reference on Publication content type to link any Publication with the concerned Profil.

Unfortunately all Profils appear in listing, which is very confusing for the user. I would like to only display french Profiles when editing/creating a french Publication (and same for english content).

[image]

I just discovered the module i18n node reference synch (https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n_node_reference), but unfortunately this module doens't provide this kind of feature.

Answer (score 0):

**If** it would be an option for you to switch from using node reference to entity reference, **then** you could try to use the [Translated Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/translated_entityreference) module. From its project page:

> ... brings better i18n support to Entity Reference field selection widget.